# Calling performUpkeep(zeroBytes) results in 'function returned an unexpected amount of data'

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, hardhat-deploy

I'm doing the blockchain course by Patrick Collins on FreeCodeCamp and I'm really enjoying it. Unfortunately I got stuck at my unit test in lesson 9 and after reading a lot of discussions on Github, I cannot come to a solution.

Can somebody please help me? :)

The issue is that I'm unable to successfully call the `performUpkeep()` function on my `Raffle.sol` smart contract.

I'm using:

- `hardhat@2.17.1`
- `ethers@6.7.1`
- typescript

I have a test file where I manipulate the time and block mined and call the `performUpkeep()` function as follows:

```typescript
describe("enterRaffle", async () => {
  it("should not allow entrance when the raffle state is set to calculating", async () => {
    await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
    const increasedInterval = Number(interval) + 10
    // manipulate time on evm
    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [increasedInterval])
    await network.provider.send("evm_mine", []);
    // calling chainlink keeper
    const zeroBytes = new Uint8Array()
    await raffle.performUpkeep(zeroBytes) // revert on this line
    await expect(raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(raffle, "Raffle__NotOpen")
  })
})
```

`raffle.performUpkeep(zeroBytes)` reverts with the following error:

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data
```

Interval is coming from my `hardhat-helper-config.ts` file that looks something like this:

```js
    "31337": {
        name: "hardhat",
        entranceFee: ethers.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane: "0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c", // doesn't matter on hh
        subscriptionId: "0",
        callbackGasLimit: "500000",
        interval: 30
    },
```

My `01-deploy-raffle.ts` file looks like this:

```typescript
const deployRaffle: DeployFunction = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments, network }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer, player } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const chainId: number = network.config.chainId!;

  let vrfCoordinatorV2Adress: (string | Addressable) | (string | undefined),
    subscriptionId: number | string | undefined,
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock;

  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer);

    vrfCoordinatorV2Adress = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.target;

    // create a subscription programmatically
    const transactionResponse: ContractTransactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription();
    const transactionReceipt: ContractTransactionReceipt = (await transactionResponse.wait()) as ContractTransactionReceipt;

    // NOT WORKING => transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;
    subscriptionId = 1;

    // fund the subscription
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT);

  } else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Adress = networkConfig[chainId].vrfCoordinatorV2;
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId].subscriptionId;
  }

  // constructer arguments
  const args = [
    vrfCoordinatorV2Adress,
    networkConfig[chainId].entranceFee,
    networkConfig[chainId].gasLane,
    subscriptionId,
    networkConfig[chainId].callbackGasLimit,
    networkConfig[chainId].interval,
  ];
  const deployOptions = {
    from: deployer,
    args: args,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: 1,
  };
  const raffle: DeployResult = await deploy("Raffle", deployOptions);
  if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    log("[deploy script] verifying contract...");
    await verify(raffle.address, args);
  }
};
export default deployRaffle;
deployRaffle.tags = ["all", "raffle"];
```

Note: I had some trouble earlier getting the subscriptionId(i.e. `subId`) from the tx logs so I opted to hardcode the `subId` to the anticipated value instead. For some reason `transactionReceipt.events[0]` does not exist on the `ContractTransactionReceipt` nor does `transactionReceipt.logs[0].args` in my local hardhat setup.

My `Raffle.sol` solidity contract looks something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/AutomationCompatible.sol";

// * errors
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatible {
    // * type declarations
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }
    // * state variables
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;
    uint256 private s_lastTimestamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;
    // * lottery variables
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;

    // * functions
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2, //contract
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimestamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    ) public view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        // (block.timestamp - lastBlockTimestamp) > interval
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimestamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance && hasPlayers);
        return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0");
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata) external override /* performData */ {
        // check if upkeep is needed
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }
        // request random number
        // revert if subscription is not set and funded.
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane, // gasLane
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        // once we get it, do something with it
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    // * view, pure functions
    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }
}
```

`performUpkeep()` seems to revert when attempting to call `requestRandomWords()`. Is it because I don't have a valid `subscriptionId` from ChainLink Keepers because I'm working locally with hardhat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was not able to fix my issue with `ethers@v6`.

I found out that my subscription simply wasn't created.

For some reason I'm unable to successfully create a subscription using this piece of code:

```typescript
await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
```

With `ethers@v5` I was able to create the subscription but got another error:

```
reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
```

For everybody reading this: Make sure to add your smart contract as a consumer at the bottom of your `01-deploy-raffle.ts` script, right after you deploy the contract.

Like this:

```typescript
    const deployOptions = {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: 1,
    };

    const raffle: DeployResult = await deploy("Raffle", deployOptions);

    if(developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        console.log("adding raffle contract as consumer");
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock?.addConsumer(subscriptionId.toNumber(), raffle.address)
        console.log("consumer added!");
    }
```